# How do I get the content portion of my http header?

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to get the content header query string returned. I'm getting a response but it does not include the query string I am trying to pass. I'm running on an Apache server.

```
$postdata = http_build_query(
                array(
                    'feed_them_social' => 'yes',
                    'refresh_token'    => get_option( 'custom_refresh_token' ),
                    'time'             => esc_html( get_option( 'custom_token_exp_time' ) ),
                )
            );
            $opts = array('http' =>
                array(
                    'method' => 'POST',
                    'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'content' => $postdata
                )
            );

            $context = stream_context_create($opts);
            
            $command = 'curl --data "' . $context . '" https://my-url.com';
            exec($command, $token);
            $output    = implode('', $token);
            print_r( $output );
```

I added this to php file on the server I am trying to get a response from. I just want to print out the header content with my query string for now but not having any luck.

```
$headers = apache_request_headers();

foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
   echo "$header: $value <br />\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stream_context_create` doesn't generate a string which you can concatenate onto a command with the `.` operator. What it does is sets up a "resource" (a memory structure, a bit like an object where everything is private) for use with selected PHP functions, such as [file_get_contents](https://php.net/file_get_contents).

If you want to use curl, use [PHP's built-in curl functions](https://www.php.net/curl), or a more user-friendly library like [Guzzle](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/).

If for some reason you really need to construct a set of command-line options, you have to do that yourself (and deal with all the risks of accidentally running the wrong thing), PHP doesn't know how to generate the right argument for `curl` or any other command.